# Running Mapreduce on files in folders and sub folders

Tags: java, unix, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Our log files are stored in year/month/day/hourly folders in HDFS

See below for structure:

```
/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=1/logA.txt    
/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=2/logB.txt    
/year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=2/logC.txt
```

If i  pass one log file as input to Java mapreduce program,  it works.

```
See my working syntax below:
hadoop jar test.jar wc /year=2014/month=8/day=20/hour=1/logA.txt output/
```

How do i pass all the files in month = 8 as input to my map reduce program?  i.e. month = 8 has folders for each day, and each day has subfolders for hours. Log files are stored in the hour folders.

I need to pass all in the files in each hour for each day in the month of August as input to my Mapreduce program.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
   hadoop jar test.jar wc /year=2014/month=8/ output/

Comment: Input path are not processed recursively. In you specify a directory is must only contain files. If it is not the case, then you have to use a glob that will only returns files

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop FileSystem supports globbing. You can find the definition of the patterns in the [FileSystem Javadoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)

To answer your specific question a pattern you could use is:

```
/year=2014/month=8/day=*/hour=*
```

If you did not provided all the details and this pattern does not work you can easily tweak it to match less files. For example:

```
/year=2014/month=8/day=*/hour=*/logA.txt
```

Or if you want to process only hours between 0 and 11

```
/year=2014/month=8/day=*/hour={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
```